# ag-grid api not working on r shiny application

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, ag-grid

I am trying to implement AG-GRID in R-Shiny, not using the custom raggrid component as unfortunately is outdated. I was able to implement everything what I wanted such as callbacks and communication between frontend and backend however I am now facing this issue.

The ag-grid api doesn't seem to be working in any way.

Feel free to run the quick example here below (tested), everything works, but when you click the button, the api function gridOptions.api.setRowData([]); is triggered and it should remove all the rows in the grid. I tried also other api calls but none of them are working, this is just the easier to implement and watch for the results.

This is the error returned to the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setRowData')
    at addItems ((index):91:21)
    at e.<anonymous> ((index):96:5)
    at e.value (shinyapp.ts:717:29)
    at e.<anonymous> (shinyapp.ts:811:16)
    at e.value (shinyapp.ts:717:29)
    at e.value (shinyapp.ts:700:12)
    at WebSocket.i.onmessage (shinyapp.ts:350:15)
```

I read online that this could happen when the api is not started, but the api should start automatically onGridReady, and the grid is actually ready, in fact adding onGridReady in the gridOtions, that event is triggered.

I am a bit lost, any hint would be appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

###################
#### JAVASCRIPT ###
###################

myscript <-'
function gridOptions(rowData) {
  return {
    columnDefs: [
      { field: "COL1" },
      { field: "COL2", 
        cellEditor: "agRichSelectCellEditor", 
        cellEditorPopup: true, 
        cellEditorParams: { values: ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"]} },        
    ],
    defaultColDef: {
      flex: 1,
      editable: true,
    },
    rowData: rowData,
    enableRangeSelection: true,
    enableFillHandle: true,
    undoRedoCellEditing: true,
    undoRedoCellEditingLimit: 5,
    enableCellChangeFlash: true,
    onCellValueChanged: onCellValueChanged,
  };
}

function onCellValueChanged(params) {
  console.log(params);
}

Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("jsondata2", function(rowData) {
  gridOptions(rowData).api.setRowData([]);
});
  
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  const gridDiv = document.querySelector("#myGrid");

  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("jsondata1", function(rowData) {
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions(rowData));
  });
  
});'

myjson <- '[
  {
    "COL1": 1,
    "COL2": "Value 1"
  },
  {
    "COL1": 2,
    "COL2": "Value 2"
  }
]'

###################
#### START DB  ####
###################

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:") 
start <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(myjson)) 
dbWriteTable(con, "requests", start) 
dbReadTable(con, "requests") 

###################
#### START APP ####
###################

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.min.js")
  ),   
  tags$script(HTML(myscript)),
  actionButton("do", "Click Me"),
  div(id = "myGrid", style="height: 300px; ", class="ag-theme-alpine")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- dbReadTable(con, "requests")
  dataJSON1<-toJSON(data)
  session$sendCustomMessage("jsondata1",dataJSON1)
  
  observeEvent(input$do, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("jsondata2",dataJSON1)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

UPDATE:
extracting gridOptions made the magic, however now I don't know how to have frontend ask for data to backend and wait for a reply at grid startup, I only know how to implement 1way communications between frontend and backend.
You can see below that I am now imputing the data as json file in the frontend javascript.

```
library(shiny)
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)

###################
#### JAVASCRIPT ###
###################

myscript <-'

const gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [
    { field: "COL1" },
    { field: "COL2", 
      cellEditor: "agRichSelectCellEditor", 
      cellEditorPopup: true, 
      cellEditorParams: { values: ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"]} },        
  ],
  defaultColDef: {
    flex: 1,
    editable: true,
  },
  rowData: getData(),
  enableRangeSelection: true,
  enableFillHandle: true,
  undoRedoCellEditing: true,
  undoRedoCellEditingLimit: 5,
  enableCellChangeFlash: true,
  onCellValueChanged: onCellValueChanged,
}

function onCellValueChanged(params) {
  console.log(params);
}

Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("jsondata2", function(rowData) {
  gridOptions.api.setRowData([]);
});

function getData() {
  return [
  {
    "COL1": 1,
    "COL2": "Value 1"
  },
  {
    "COL1": 2,
    "COL2": "Value 2"
  }
];
}
  
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  const gridDiv = document.querySelector("#myGrid");
  new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
  
});'

myjson <- '[
  {
    "COL1": 1,
    "COL2": "Value 1"
  },
  {
    "COL1": 2,
    "COL2": "Value 2"
  }
]'

###################
#### START DB  ####
###################

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:") 
start <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(myjson)) 
dbWriteTable(con, "requests", start) 
dbReadTable(con, "requests") 

###################
#### START APP ####
###################

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.min.js")
  ),   
  tags$script(HTML(myscript)),
  actionButton("do", "Click Me"),
  div(id = "myGrid", style="height: 300px; ", class="ag-theme-alpine")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- dbReadTable(con, "requests")
  dataJSON1<-toJSON(data)
  session$sendCustomMessage("jsondata1",dataJSON1)
  
  observeEvent(input$do, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("jsondata2",dataJSON1)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
dbDisconnect(con)
```

Comment: The problem is here: **gridOptions.api.setRowData([])**. Don't you forget the argument of the **gridOptions** function? **gridOptions(ARGUMENT).api.setRowData([])**

Comment: nice input @StéphaneLaurent thank you for it :) I modified the example, now I am sending the json file over also in the apicall callback, so I can have gridOptions(rowData) called with its argument. however it is still not working. same problem.

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps **tags$script(HTML(myscript))**.

Comment: unfortunately not working @StéphaneLaurent , example updated with HTML tag. thanks for the try, your help has been precious lately :)

Comment: **gridOptions** returns an ordinary JS object, so why would it have the **api** key?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent  this is how the ag-grid api is called, you can check this example https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/data-update-transactions/#example-updating-with-transaction

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I was actually able to make it work. I made gridOptions an actual object not a function, in this way it works. but in this way I can't use rowData as parameter to the function, while I request data using the getData function. So I don't know how to have frontend ask for data and wait for backend to return data at initialisation. I updated the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I would try that:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  function onCellValueChanged(params) {
    console.log(params);
  }

  function gridOptions(rowData) {
    return {
      columnDefs: [
        { field: "COL1" },
        {
          field: "COL2",
          cellEditor: "agRichSelectCellEditor",
          cellEditorPopup: true,
          cellEditorParams: { values: ["Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3"] }
        }
      ],
      defaultColDef: {
        flex: 1,
        editable: true
      },
      rowData: rowData,
      enableRangeSelection: true,
      enableFillHandle: true,
      undoRedoCellEditing: true,
      undoRedoCellEditingLimit: 5,
      enableCellChangeFlash: true,
      onCellValueChanged: onCellValueChanged
    };
  }

  const gridDiv = document.querySelector("#myGrid");
  var gridOptionsObject;

  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("jsondata1", function (rowData) {
    gridOptionsObject = gridOptions(rowData);
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptionsObject);
  });

  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("jsondata2", function (rowData) {
    gridOptionsObject.api.setRowData([]);
  });

});
```